# fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I was using type hinting as shown below in the code, but fastapi is trying to check something which I am not aware of due to which I was not able to run the code.

**Code:**

```
# from db.models import User
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
class UserRepository:
    def __init__(self, db: Session): <-- error line
        self.db = db

    def get_all_users(self):
        return self.db.query(User).all()

@router.get("/")  # , response_model=User - if add this, it is throwing similar error i.e., fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'db.models.user.User'> is a valid Pydantic field type.
async def read_users(
    phone_number: str = Depends(get_phone_number), repo: UserRepository = Depends()
):
    return repo.get_all_users()
```

**Error:**

```
> fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field!
> Hint: check that <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session'> is a valid
> Pydantic field type. If you are using a return type annotation that is
> not a valid Pydantic field (e.g. Union[Response, dict, None]) you can
> disable generating the response model from the type annotation with
> the path operation decorator parameter response_model=None. Read more:
> https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/
```

If I use `BaseModel` from pydantic as type hinting,

```
class SessionModel(BaseModel):
    __root__: Session

...
def __init__(self, db:SessionModel): <-- error line
    self.db = db
```

Then it throws `no validator found error` :|

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're passing a session as a parameter? Generally, I would wrap the session in a database.py file with helper functions and use those helper functions to interface with the database.

Comment: @SimonUnderwood Getting the similar error for when `response_model=User`, how to handle that? There is no specific reason, can you please share your suggested approach with some example code for understanding?

Comment: The response model isn't the issue here. The issue is that you are trying to pass a db session as a parameter to an endpoint. You should never do that. Instead, put anything that has to do with db sessions in a separate file and make all the access functions in that file. Then in the rest of your code, use those functions to interact with db sessions.

Comment: @SimonUnderwood Oh, okay, got you! Thanks for highlighting. It requires only phone number to fetch user details, but there is `HttpBearer` is used as Authentication, so I am seeing `db` and `Authentication` as parameters to an endpoint.